# How to draw filled polygon on QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsscene, qcolor

I want to draw a polygon filled with a specific color on QGraphicsScene. Then I use the following codes:

```
QPolygonF poly;
poly << QPointF(10, 10) << QPointF(10, 50) << QPointF(30, 70 )<< QPointF(60, 50) << QPointF(50, 10);
QBrush brush;
brush.setColor(Qt::red);
QPen pen(Qt::green);
QGraphicsScene graphics_scene_ = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,200,200);
graphics_scene_->addPolygon(poly, pen, brush);
setScene(graphics_scene_);
```

However I only get a hollow polygon with green border, but without red fill inside the polygon.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QBrush()` is missing the style. You should use:

```
QBrush brush
brush.setColor(Qt::red);
brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
```

Or better this way since the `Qt::SolidPattern` style comes by default:

```
QBrush brush(Qt::red);
```